Is angular velocity frame invariant at non-relativistic speeds?
What is the magnitude of the angular velocity vector with respect to a stationary reference frame and a moving reference frame?  Is it the same for both frames? For example, suppose there is a disk rotating on a vertical axis attached to a truck bed that is moving at 10 meter per second relative to an observer on the ground.  The disk is rotating at 10 radians per second relative to an observer on the truck bed. When the truck bed passes an observer on the ground will he also measure the angular velocity of the disk to be 10 radians per second?  That is, is angular velocity frame invariant?

It is, only in the sense that most people are smart enough to guess what you mean and switch to some sense of the truck’s perspective to answer your question.
You don't even need the truck to be going at any particular speed. Imagine the truck is at rest and the circle rotates at unit period, so from the truck’s perspective (i.e. origin at the center of the circle, $\theta=0$ points in the direction the truck points, we stick a dot on the circle and track the angle made relative to the origin), it is moving at $\omega=2\pi.$ I am going to be at some other location, and I am going to point at dot on the circle on the truck, and measure the angle of my arm relative to my orientation forwards.
Now wait, there is one detail I didn't mention: this truck is on the moon, I am on Earth. The motion of my arm is absolutely imperceptible and with respect to this origin $\omega\approx 0,$ and maybe oscillates between being a tiny positive rate and a tiny negative rate. (Well, I mean, you'll actually find $\omega\approx 2\pi/\text{day}$ due to the rotation of the Earth I guess.)
But if you ask me “what rate do you think the circle is rotating,” the point is I would never think to point at a dot on the circle and measure the angle relative to me. I would identify the center of rotation first! And probably the axis of rotation. And only then will I try to answer the question.
There is a question somewhat like this, but replacing angular velocity with angular momentum, and that is much much more tractable, it turns out there is something called the parallel axis theorem that has you completely covered for that.

Consider the wheel of a vehicle moving along a road in a reference frame where the road is stationary. Let say the wheel completes one revolution in one second as the vehicle advance along the road. In the reference frame that is at rest with the vehicle the wheel still completes one revolution in one second. In the Newtonian context, one second is the same in either reference frame so the the angular velocity is considered frame invariant.
In the relativistic case, the angular velocity is reduced by a factor equal to the relativistic gamma factor $\gamma = \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ due to time dilation, where v is the relative velocity of the truck the flywheel is mounted on. For $v << c$ such that $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \approx 1$ the angular velocity can be considered frame invariant to a reasonable approximation because the time dilation factor can be considered negligible, at every day velocities.
